# Click on element within an iframe with no src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've been struggling with this one for a few hours now.
I am trying to attach click listeners to elements within an iframe with no src attribute. The entire page is basically inside that bad boy.

When I use "inspect element", the body of iframe looks empty (dunno if that has to do with the fact it has no src attribute.

```js
<iframe id="CoverIframe" name="CoverIframe">
  #document
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

When I enter the ID of the iframe in the console, it simply returns null, which prevents me from checking the elements it contains via contents().find() or anything else for that matter. I can only see its content (and by extension the elements on the page) by showing the source code (right click>see source).

Any thoughts on this? Is it because of the absence of src attribute? Any way I can get around it?

Thanks,
Alexis

Comment: Where's the javascript?

Comment: To be honest, your implementation sounds a little strange. iframes are generally used to embed other documents in your page. If you're leaving the src attribute blank, thus not embedding another document, why use an iframe in the first place? Perhaps we can help you find a better solution that will achieve your desired result instead of using an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you can't just set the innerDocument of an iframe like that.
However, you can use its (**html-5 only**)[`srcDoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc) attribute to set it,

```html
<iframe id="CoverIframe" name="CoverIframe" srcdoc="
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>hello</body>
    </html>"
        ></iframe>
```

or use a `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>"`.

```html
<iframe id="CoverIframe" name="CoverIframe" src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>hello</body>
    </html>"
        ></iframe>
```

But for the later, you will soon need to `encodeURI()` your page.
So the best is probably using javascript :

```html
<script>
  var yourHTML = "<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>";
  function loadFrame(e){e.contentDocument.write(yourHTML)};
</script>

<iframe id="CoverIframe" name="CoverIframe" onload="loadFrame(this)">
```

[►  Show code fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv73n69c/)

Comment: Hey Kaiido, thank you for your response. I wish it was as simple as me changing the way the frame is set up, but I am simply working on a client's website and don't have much control over the source code. All i can/need to do is insert custom scripts via a tag management system. What i dont understand is that the iframe is only blank when using inspect element, but not when showing the source code. Any idea why?

Comment: well what is inside the iframe tag (between `<iframe>`and `</iframe>` is only rendered if the iframe element is not supported by browser/user agent (apparently some mobile browsers and xhtml parsers), or if the user disabled them. So it is normal that it's not rendered when your browser does support iframes. For your goal, if you can access through javascript, take a look at `iframe.contentWindow.document`, an error should be thrown if you can't access it due to CORS. Anyway, you might find somewhere in the sources how this iframe is populated, and may be able to insert your scripts in it.